# How to redirect stderr of sub process started by Python multiprocessing.Process()

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm using Python `multiprocessing.Process()` to start sub process. For some unknown reason, the sub process doesn't start successfully. I'm trying to find out why. However, there is no error massage printed.

I already redirect stdout and stderr of the parent process to a log file. But I don't know how to do that to the sub process. I noticed that Python subprocess lib is more flexible, but I prefer multiprocessing because it offers more convenient tools for synchronization between processes.

Please help.

Comment: `multiprocessing.Process` just runs a python function. Just use `contextlib.redirect_stderr` from python `how to do that to the sub proces` Just `sys.stderr = where you want stderr to go`

Comment: @KamilCuk The thing is,  `sys.stderr = where` need to be run in the sub process, but the sub process is not running properly, so it may not get the change to run the line, and that is the problem I want to deal with.

Comment: So you suspect that the sole act of `multiprocessing.Process` is not starting? Post an [MCVE]. It's just executing `fork()` (on linux). Is `exitcode` set? what is the output of `str(process)`?

Comment: @KamilCuk I put it in another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77713003/python-multiprocessing-no-module-named-xxx-problem

Comment: @KamilCuk But how to redirct the stderr of multiprocessing.Process() is really another thing I'm interested.

Comment: @KamilCuk I see. Unfortunately, I'm using Windows. It seems inherits nothing of parent process. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to a file within the subprocess function. This approach is beneficial for debugging, as it captures all console output generated by the subprocess:

```py
import sys
import multiprocessing

def subprocess_function():
    sys.stdout = open('subprocess_stdout.log', 'w')
    sys.stderr = open('subprocess_stderr.log', 'w')
    
    # Your subprocess code here
    print("This will be logged in subprocess_stdout.log")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=subprocess_function)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

In this code snippet, stdout and stderr are redirected to `subprocess_stdout.log` and `subprocess_stderr.log`, respectively.

Or better use logging module. You can configure it to write logs to a file, which is useful for debugging.

```py
import logging
import multiprocessing

def worker():
    logging.basicConfig(filename='subprocess.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.debug("This is a debug message from subprocess")
    # Your subprocess code here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```